# Bevel not visible, only in back face

Tags: bevel

I have a problem when[image] applying Bevel to edge, it is not visible and it seems to be created on the back side. I checked face Normals, and all are correct. See attached picture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely you have duplicate vertices.

Comment: Hi Cegaton, when I select a single edge there are only 2 vertex selected; I tried also with "B" click and drag select and there is only 1 edge (2 vertex). There must be another reason. Thank you.